# How can i pronounce letter 'a' correctly?

Tags: pronunciation

I've read different questions about pronouncing 'a' like this :
[Sounds of the letter a](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7998/sounds-of-the-letter-a)

In my native tongue-Arabic- there are 3 degrees of pronouncing 'a'

- degree one is like *able*
- degree two is like *marry*
- degree three is like *are*

My confusion is in 2 things:

1. The symbols used in answers like æ, ə, etc. are difficult to me (please guide me how to understand them)
2. Can you tell me when specifically should I use each one of these three degrees?

Comment: Those pronunciation symbols are part of the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). Please do your research.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost The international IPA symbols and the ones used specifically for English have different values. They represent different types of sounds. Also the Original Poster is asking about sound/spelling correspondence - which isn't covered by the IPA, or even by most coursebooks. So I think it's a fair question.

Comment: @Araucaria This is why I didn't file a close vote. I was seeing how he has problems understanding those symbols.

Comment: Long: the *-ey* in "They". Short: the *-a* in "hat/cat/bat/rat/chat..."

Comment: @lurker That is only basic building blocks. Get "Amelia", "usage", "a", and "martial" and you'll have a problem.

Comment: I agree with you (and like your answer) but some of those words are French :)

Comment: Hmmm... Schwas derive from stress patterns, /ɑ/ mostly appears before letters R and L.

Answer (score 5):

There is no consistent rule. English spelling is a harsh mistress. You'll have to pick up each case separately.

To demonstrate:

> **a**, c**a**t, M**a**rs, **a**ble, us**a**ge,

have respectively /ə, æ, ɑ, eɪ, ɪ/.

Dictionaries to look up IPA pronunciations in may help you.

For the symbols:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English

The IPA symbols are a bit different between English and others. Most notably in their R sounds, T's, and sometimes vowels too.

For IPA transcriptions, try Dictionary.com, Macmillan Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionaries Online, Wiktionary, ...

Also, Dictionary.com transcribes /j/ (the Y consonant) as /y/ (a vowel sound that doesn't exist in English) for some reason.